# simple SQL update query error that i have no idea how to solve

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I have two tables:

> PS(size(primary key), price)
>   Sales(....size,quantity, total_Price)

I tried to execute this statement:

```
 update Sales
                set total_Price = (select price from PS, Sales 
where Sales.size = PS.size )*Quantity;
```

but i get this error always

> SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or
>   VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.

I know that the error is because the sub query i used in the select statement returns more than one row, that's why i can't work. Can someone please help me solve this problem.

Comment: heeeeeeeeeelp pleaaaaaase

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING size in PS is UNIQUE

```
update Sales
set total_Price = (SELECT max(PS.price) FROM PS PS
                  INNER JOIN  Sales S on S.Size = PS.Size)*Quantity;
```

The problem I think is that your sales table contains multiple entries per size.  Thus it's duplicate the price in the PS table.  You either need the max price from that table, or the distinct value ASSUMING size is a unique value in the PS table.  If size is NOT unique in the PS table then I would need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually the size is unique in the PS table. what i want is not the maximum price, i want only the price of the particular size in the  Sales table that's all. the command u posted just now gives me only the maximum price which is actually not what's needed here. can you please help me find a way to get what's required to do, thank you